# Horizontal Alignment of Ipywidgets / Interactive plotting

Tags: matplotlib, ipywidgets

The goal ist to:

- plot data based on a dropdown value
- have multiple plots based on the same value
- align them in a row (horizontal).

In my case the interactive_plot is the box with all plots in it, therefore I can't style them how I want it. How do I plot the two plots in one line?

```
def showMADetails(column=filter_unique):
plt.figure(1)
filtered_ma = ma_data[(ma_data['2'] == column)]
plt.bar(column, filtered_ma['GrossTurnoverBudget'], align='center', alpha=0.5)

plt.figure(2)
filtered_ma = ma_data[(ma_data['2'] == column)]
plt.bar(column, filtered_ma['Productive billableDays'], align='center', alpha=0.5)

interactive_plot = interactive(showMADetails)
output = interactive_plot.children[1]
output.layout.height = '400px'
output.layout.width = '200px'

interactive_plot
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out that I was wrong. The plots aren't widgets, so I followed a wrong approach.
The interactive_plot controls the UI of the widgets.

To control the plots itself I need to control the layout via subplots. That is the solution.